# How to assign string to vector(both on heap)

Tags: c++, string, pointers, vector, heap-memory

I am trying to get roughly 3 milion strings from file to the vector. I allocated  it like this

```
vector<string> *slownikds = new vector<string>;
```

And when I try to push back from file like this:

```
string *line;   
while (getline(slownik, *line))
    {
            *slownikds->push_back(*line);
    }
```

It doesn't work. How can push back strings from file "slownik"?

Comment: Usually creating a vector dynamically doesn't provide any benefits. It already stores all its data dynamically behind the scenes. Same with `std::string`'s

Comment: `slownikds` is `vect`?

Comment: Note that strings and vectors store their contents on heap regardless of whether you used `new` to create them or not.

Comment: Also your code is not pushing a string into your vector because you have not allocated a string for that pointer. It's pointing into random space right now.

Comment: It's highly unlikely you need or want to create vectors, strings or other containers dynamically.

Answer (score 7):

Please stop this.

`std::vector` is created so that you don't have to allocate memory for a container yourself. `std::string` is there so that you don't have to use `char *` or resort to using fixed size buffers.

Please fix:

```
std::vector<string> slownikds;
std::string line;   
while (getline(slownik, line)) {
    slownikds.push_back(line);
}
```

---

The reason you are getting an "error" can be one of three things:

1. You did not initialize your `*line`, so it is pointing to uninitialized memory or possibly `NULL`
2. You are trying to access a member function `push_back` via the pointer member access operator
3. Something foobar

In any case, **not** using pointers like I did above, is the answer